# Image is not displaying in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources

I have tried all combinations to display image in my jsp.
But still image is not displaying.

I'm attaching Screenshot for the same.
[image]

In server Im getting this error

```
**[![Jun 21, 2016 11:16:40 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/guestbook-webapp/images/Alarm_Tick_Icon_32.png\] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jun 21, 2016 11:22:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/guestbook-webapp/images/Alarm_Tick_Icon_32.png\] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jun 21, 2016 11:22:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/guestbook-webapp/src/images/Alarm_Tick_Icon_32.png\] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'][1]][1]**
```

Comment: where is the location of the jsp file. Try add the full code of the jsp file

Comment: i have updated the image please have a look

Comment: try moving the pages folder outside the WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC handles resources differently with simple configuration requirement in `spring-dispatcher.xml` file.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

In your case, I think your Spring MVC XML file is in `spring-config` folder, and you need to configure the MVC resource tag exactly this way:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

And, have your JSP file include the JSTL library on top of the page and then fetch the image as shown below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<img src="<c:url value="/images/Alarm_Tick_Icon_32.png"/>"/>
```

This was tested on my local server and proven to be successful. Please let us know whether this approach works out on your end, or you need more examples from `web.xml` or `spring-dispatcher.xml` files.